# How to check if a path exists in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have JS function that creates a url to the appropriate pdf file based on an option that the user has already chosen.

I have most of the function sorted out but I'd just like to know how to check if the path to the pdf file actually exists in case the users version hasn't got all the pdf's downloaded.

For now I'll just need an alert(); as an example to see what needs to be done but here's my current code

```
function pdfSelected(selected) {
  keyNumberStr = keyNumber.toString();
  pdfDisplay = "pdf/key" + keyNumberStr + selected + ".pdf";
  if (selected === "summary" || registered) {
    //Insert Code To Check File Existence
    window.location.href = pdfDisplay;
  }
  else {
    window.alert("This option is only available to registered users");
  }
}
```

I've added a comment where I need to the do the check for whether the file exists or not.  If it exists, go straight to the pdf.  Else display an alert to tell the user that the file is missing.

Comment: Would it be easier to check, if user is registered, or even remove unavailable options at the first place?

Comment: That's actually quite a good idea.  I'm doing this for someone else so I'll ask them about it before doing that.  Anyway, that'll be something else I do once I get this done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to remove the options up front if a user isn't registered, this is a way better UX for the user because it prevent them from performing a forbidden action in the first place.